# C# .Net application freezes when writing to the file

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I have a .net compact framework 3.5, c# win form application running on Windows embedded 
compact 7.

The application gets lot of data (approx. 100 KB  per 30 milliseconds) in the form of byte array , the app receives the data and stores that data in the file and send the data to the forms where it gets displayed live in graphical form (graphs).

The app runs fine for a while but then suddenly everything stops.
Don't know what to do nor how to debug ?

One thread which receives the data and another thread saves the data to the file and one GUI thread which is displaying the data.

I have many charting controls which are displaying the data in various graphs.

Any suggestions/guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: We'd need to see some code - It sounds like you've got a dead lock in the code that synchronizes the file + GUI + receiving of the data...

Comment: @ReedCopsey How can I detect the deadlock sir, the GUI works actually but gets very very slow.

Comment: Have you profiled the app, to see if you're leaking resources, etc?

Comment: @ReedCopsey: I have profiled and the memory usage seems to be constant. Maybe GUI thread is not getting invoked coz the thread which is saving to the file is working all the time, it is just a guess, is it possibleto find out what is going on when the app slowsdown ?

Comment: What about resource utilization?  Handles are a common issue... With no code, there's no real way to help, though

Comment: In the question you state app runs fine for a while and the suddenly everything stops and in a comment you state GUI works but gets very very slow.  Inconsistent problem statement and no code.

Answer (score 0):

Your GUI slows down but keeps working after a while. It seems as if you're exhausting a resource, and the OS tries to compensate. My guess is memory - are you perhaps leaking memory? Make sure the memory you use in the secondary thread is freed.